# автоответ на указанный адрес в outlook 2016

Tags: email, outlook

Привет! не получается настроить автоматический ответ на письмо по условию
помогите разобраться.
приходит письмо от адреса1(этот фильтр я указываю в настройках правила) 
ставлю фильтр по тексту в теме("тест") 
письмо приходит не конкретно мне, а группе людей, в которой есть мой адрес(на адрес2) 
с этим фильтром у меня и проблема... что необходимо указать? пробовал разные варианты - не работает 
далее необходимо ответить на адрес2 определенным текстом(я сделал просто переслать сообщение от адреса1 на адрес2 с подписью, которая содержит нужный текст)